# Is it possible to suppress `LSP :: Connected to [pyls:N].` message on minibuffer?

Tags: message, lsp, inhibit-message

When I open a Python file I keep seeing `LSP :: Connected to [pyls:N]` message in the minibuffer. How can I suppress it?

Since I know I have enabled `lsp`, I don't want to see that message always whenever I open a new file. I have looked into  https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/tutorials/how-to-turn-off but I couldn't find an option to disable it.

*my configuration*:

```lisp
(require 'lsp-mode)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'lsp)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'lsp-deferred)
(setq lsp-enable-symbol-highlighting nil)
(setq lsp-ui-doc-enable nil)
(setq lsp-lens-enable nil)
(setq lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-enable nil)
(setq lsp-ui-sideline-enable nil)
(setq lsp-diagnostics-provider :none)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```lisp
(defun disable-lsp-conn-msg-advice (func &rest r)
  (unless (string-prefix-p "Connected to" (car r))
    (apply func r)))

(advice-add 'lsp--info :around #'disable-lsp-conn-msg-advice)
```

Comment: Woaw that was a fast answer thank you

Comment: @alper Glad to help. Fast since it's easy. 

Comment: Its not related to `lsp` but I also keep seeing `Fill column set to 80 (was 80)` is it possible to suppress it too?

Comment: @alper Bottom line you would have to discover its origin to try advising it.

Comment: Seems like it suppresses the connection message but also prevents the `LSP` to be connected

Comment: @alper No it should not be a factor. Works fine on my machine.

Comment: I double verify that it works on my end too